# Lexical fault when using ''BOOM!''

Tags: haskell

I type this into my texteditor:

```
boombang xs = [ if x < 10 then ”BOOM!” else ”BANG!”
```

But when trying to load it, my terminal denies it and and says:

[image: Says there's something wrong with my quotation marks]

Probably some dumb rookie mistake, but I can't seem to find the solution...:/

Comment: You copied that code from somewhere? Type quotes by hand.

Comment: You need to use the regular quotes ", not any fancy version of them.

Comment: What are you writing your programs with? You should use a programmer's editor or IDE, not something that replaces ”straight quotes” (inches) with ”curly quotes” in order to ”fix” them for you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here.

The first is, you're not using plain ASCII quotation marks (U+0022) `"`. You're using right quotation marks (U+201D) `”`. There's probably a keyboard setting you're using that's causing this, and using certain text editing programs can also prevent this.

Secondly, you seem to be either missing a right bracket. As pointed out, this is probably meant to be part of a list comprehension. You need to write *all* of the list comprehension for it to work.

The corrected code is:

```
boombang xs = [if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- xs]
```

Comment: From the look of it, it’s supposed to be part of a list comprehension like `[if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- xs]`